# Update trigger with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers

With these two tables :

Table A:

```
 key integer
 field varchar
```

Table B

```
oldkey integer
oldfield varchar
newkey integer
newfield varchar
```

I want to archive all operations on A in B.

It is easy to do for INSERT or DELETE statements, but how to do that with UPDATE ones ? Especially for multiple rows UPDATE statements, of course...

Here is my actual trigger :

```
create trigger mytrigger 
on TableA
after insert, update, delete
as
begin
    declare @wAction char(1);

    set @wAction = (case 
                       when exists (select 1 from INSERTED)
                            and exists (select 1 from DELETED)   
                          then 'U'
                       when exists (select 1 from INSERTED)  
                          then 'I'
                       when exists (select 1 from DELETED)   
                          then 'X'
                       else ''
                    end);

    if (@wAction = 'I') 
    begin
        insert into TableB 
            select null, null, key, field 
            from inserted;    
    end
    else if (@wAction = 'X') 
    begin
        insert into TableB 
            select key, field, null, null 
            from deleted;    
    end
    else if (@wAction = 'U') 
    begin
        --    BUT WHAT TO DO THERE ?
    end
end
```

I read [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/create-dml-triggers-to-handle-multiple-rows-of-data?view=sql-server-ver15) that using cursors in triggers is not recommended, but I have no other idea...

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
else if (@wAction = 'U') 
begin
    insert into TableB (oldkey, oldvalue, newkey, newvalue)
        select d.key, d.field, i.key, i.field
        from deleted d
        inner join inserted i on d.key = i.key;
end
```

This **assumes** the `key`  is the primary key and doesn't change. If that's not the case - then you need to join `Inserted` (new values after update) and `Deleted` (old values before update) on whatever other **primary key** column you have that is stable and doesn't change during an `UPDATE` ...

Comment: thx but every field of the table might be changed, including the key...

Comment: There **ought to be** some **primary key** that doesn't change - otherwise, you cannot make the connection between the `Inserted` and the `Deleted` pseudo tables in the `UPDATE` trigger.....